# Как вытащить значение из URL и поставить его в текст сайта

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Есть URL вида /index-2.html?name=second&user_profile_color_1=1&money=first

Необходимо, чтобы значения second и first вставлялись в соответствующие места на сайте

```
<h4>Transfer successfully! <br> <b>Process 24Hr</b> and the amount <p id="first"> **сюда** </p> to <p id="second"> **сюда** </p></h4>
```

Как это сделать с помощью JS? Буду благодарен!

Comment: А какие вы попытки сделали для решения?

Comment: И при чем тут тег [php]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, что бы расставить значения из параметров URL, нам потребуется при загрузке страницы запускать функцию, которая будет доставать нужные данные и вставлять их в соответствующие элементы DOM дерева.

Вставляете данный код в ваш js файл или в тег `<script></script>`

```
window.onload = function () { // Сработает при загрузке страницы
  window.location.search // Берем данные из URL
    .replace('?', '') // Убираем первый ?
    .split('&') // Разбиваем строку на массив вида key=value
    .map(el => el.split('=')) // Разбиваем каждый элемент на массив [key, value]
    .filter(it => it[0] === 'money' || it[0] === 'name') //Фильтруем, оставляя нужное
    .forEach(el => { // Для каждого найденного вставляем значения
      document.getElementById(el[0]).innerText = el[1];
    });
}
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что для "красоты", вставка данных идет для элементов с id name и money

```
<h4>Transfer successfully! <br> <b>Process 24Hr</b> and the amount <p id="money"> **сюда** </p> to <p id="name"> **сюда** </p></h4>
```

Если вы не хотите или не можете изменить id элементов, то в цикле forEach надо будет внести изменения и добавить "перекодировку" на соответствие ключа из URL id элемента на странице

```
.forEach(el => { // Для каждого найденного вставляем значения
  const elemId = el[0] === 'name' ? 'second' : 'first';
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerText = el[1];
});
```

По подсказке из комментария от [@OliverPatterson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/423297/oliver-patterson)

> ***А почему не используется urlsearchparams?***

Обратиться к ключам в URL можно так же:

```
const url = new URL(window.location);
document.getElementById('first').innerText = url.searchParams.get('money');
document.getElementById('second').innerText = url.searchParams.get('name');
```

Comment: А почему не используется `urlsearchparams`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson потому что я про это забыл :)

Comment: да, ваше решение помогло, спасибо. Только вот, если переменная в URL написана на русском языке, то выдает ошибку :(

Comment: @Матвей Переменная или значение? Что за ошибка?

Comment: если name у нас будет на русском языке, то в поле будут возникать вот такие символы: Process 24Hr and the amount $10587 to %D0%B0%D0%B0%D0%B0

Comment: @Матвей Используйте фукнцию `decodeURI`. Пример: `document.getElementById(el[0]).innerText = decodeURI(el[1]);`

Comment: отличное решение, спасибо большое!